# Download specific chart kube-prometheus-stack-23.1.0 to my local

Tags: prometheus, helm3

I want to install specific `kube-prometheus-stack-23.1.0` version on my eks cluster. When I ran this command helm repo add prometheus-community `https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts` It is adding the latest chart.

When I am running below command I am getting this error
`helm upgrade prometheus -n monitoring -f prom-v1.yaml prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack-23.1.0 --version 23.1.0 --debug`

`Error: chart "kube-prometheus-stack-23.1.0" matching not found in prometheus-community index. (try 'helm repo update'): no chart name found`

can someone pl help me on how to download specific chart `kube-prometheus-stack-23.1.0` to my local

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the repo installed:

1- just lists all the versions as a double check

```
helm search repo prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -l
```

2- execute the install

helm install [NAME] [CHART] [flags]

Name=mystack(Provide a friendly name)

Chart=prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
flags= --version 23.1.0

```
helm install mystack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --version 23.1.0
```

Comment: Version 23.1.0 is not there in my local.. when I added helm repo prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack it is downloading the latest chart locally. I want to download 23.1.0 chart locally. How to do it.

Comment: how did you added the repo ?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can clone the specific version in local and then try installing it , using below command
2. after cloning cd to kube-prometheus-stack directory where your values.yaml is there , from there you can run the below command

3.`helm install my-prom(you can name anything as this is release name) prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f values.yaml --version 23.1.0`

if you are unable to clone specific version let me know